# Java Graphics/ Basic Game Loop

Tags: java, graphics

I'm creating a galaga clone in java. I am trying to understand the basics of a game loop and I have a couple problems/ questions. I have an update method that changes the positions of all the game objects and I have a draw method that draws all the updated positions of said objects. Should I ever call the paint() method? How do I repaint the objects (clear the screen then draw everything again)? Also, what is the best way to call my update() method at a fixed rate? Thanks for any input.

```
public Galaga() throws IOException
{
    //set the background
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    //create a controller
    c = new Controller();
    addKeyListener(c);
    setFocusable(true);

    //create a player
    player = new Ship(40,50);
    running = true;

}


public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
}

//game loop
public void run()
{
    while(running)
    {
        draw(getGraphics());
        if(c.right())
            player.move(1, 0);
    }
}

//update logic
public void update()
{

}

//renders all objects
public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    player.draw(g);
}
```

Comment: You call `repaint()` or switch to [active rendering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html)

Comment: If you just want to learn about Swing, what you are doing is fine.  However, if you're actually intending to make a game, [Swing probably won't work well for you.](https://pavelfatin.com/low-latency-painting-in-awt-and-swing/)  There are [better options for games.](https://www.lwjgl.org/)

Answer (score 0):

> I have an update method that changes the positions of all the game objects

Yep, good

> and I have a draw method that draws all the updated positions of said objects

Ah...not so good

> Should I ever call the paint() method?

No, you should never have to do this, in fact, you shouldn't be call `getGraphics` either, this is not how painting is done.

You would normally call `repaint` to trigger a new paint cycle.

Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for how painting works in Swing - I'm assuming you're using Swing based on the methods you're using

Also, beware, Swing is single thread - see [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more a simple solution.

If you still want to use a `Thread`, beware, that painting can occur at any time for any number of reasons, which are beyond your control, so you need to be aware of the risk of dirty paints when update states

If you want more control over the paint/update cycle, then you should have a look at [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is really good code for a game-loop found [here](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0). Thought I would just share this link to save people time!

Use the loop with the fixed time-step. The code can be greatly simplified, as the code creates a bouncing ball example to show the interpolation of frames for smoothness and the benefits of that type of loop.

I have created a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/QtH2StuS) with my simplified version of the code from the website above. I separated the game loop into separate classes, and added more comments in the code to show what is happening. This makes it easier to create your own game without going through the whole game loop to see what's happening and how it works.

Let me know any suggestions to my pastebin version, and I will update it :)

Folder layout:

```
src
|
|--app
  |
  |--game
  | |
  | |--logic
  | | .--Game.java
  | |--loop
  |   .--GameLoop.java
  |   .--GamePanel.java
  |
  .--App.java
  .--Window.java
```